# how to attach document in custom list for sharepoint online using Powershell?

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, powershell, attachments

I have tried this code to attach a document in custom list for sharepoint online, but it is not working.

```
$site = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]("Your site name")  
$web = $site.OpenWeb()  
$list = $web.Lists["Your List name"]  
$item = $list.GetItemById(Your Id)  
AddAttachment $item "Your Document Name"  

function AddAttachment($item, $filePath)  
{  
    $bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filePath)  
    $item.Attachments.Add([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($filePath),$bytes)  
    $item.Update()  
}
```

Comment: You have to use PowerShell based on client side object model in order to work on SP Online.

Comment: yes Nadeem I am doing that but it is not working ,I think there is something missing in the code But I am not able to find.

Comment: The code you have written is server side code.

Comment: oh okay. I will check and will let you know. Can you provide code for the same as I am new to Sharepoint. Thanks

Comment: check this on how to get started http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2015/03/sharepoint-online-create-list-using.html

Comment: thanks nadeem but I have already created list Now I want to attach document to the custom list when adding a new item using powershell. So could you help me out ?

Comment: check this post. It show how to add attachments using CSOM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969810/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-add-attachment-to-listitem. You will need to convert the code into PowerSehll

Answer (score 0):

May be an old post, but it looks like you are calling AddAttachment before defining it. Put the function definition at the top.